# How do you change the limits of a Linux system account or a user that does not login to shell

Tags: linux, shell

I am running a Linux VM and I have a user that needs modified ulimits for the processes that user spawns. However this is a system account user (for example, apache) and the user never actually logs into the shell to spawn processes, they are spawned from an init.d or systemd script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For services started via `systemd`, you could easily add limits by editing service files. read `man systemd.exec`

```
  Table 1. Limit directives and their equivalent with ulimit
   ┌────────────────┬───────────────────┐
   │Directive       │ ulimit equivalent │
   ├────────────────┼───────────────────┤
   │LimitCPU        │ ulimit -t         │
   ├────────────────┼───────────────────┤
   │LimitFSIZE      │ ulimit -f         │
   ├────────────────┼───────────────────┤
   │LimitDATA       │ ulimit -d         │
   ├────────────────┼───────────────────┤
   │LimitSTACK      │ ulimit -s         │
   ├────────────────┼───────────────────┤
   │LimitCORE       │ ulimit -c         │
   ├────────────────┼───────────────────┤
   │LimitRSS        │ ulimit -m         │
   ├────────────────┼───────────────────┤
   │LimitNOFILE     │ ulimit -n         │
   ├────────────────┼───────────────────┤
   │LimitAS         │ ulimit -v         │
   ├────────────────┼───────────────────┤
   │LimitNPROC      │ ulimit -u         │
   ├────────────────┼───────────────────┤
   │LimitMEMLOCK    │ ulimit -l         │
   ├────────────────┼───────────────────┤
   │LimitLOCKS      │ ulimit -x         │
   ├────────────────┼───────────────────┤
   │LimitSIGPENDING │ ulimit -i         │
   ├────────────────┼───────────────────┤
   │LimitMSGQUEUE   │ ulimit -q         │
   ├────────────────┼───────────────────┤
   │LimitNICE       │ ulimit -e         │
   ├────────────────┼───────────────────┤
   │LimitRTPRIO     │ ulimit -r         │
   ├────────────────┼───────────────────┤
   │LimitRTTIME     │ No equivalent     │
   └────────────────┴───────────────────┘
```

For init.d script's you could setup limits via `ulimit`

Answer (score 0):

Modifying the /etc/system/limits.conf file or adding a file to limits.d can limit user or group maximum system resources using pam_limits.so. This also prevents fork bombing as it applies to the users total system resources used across all the users' processes. The following line must also be added to the file /etc/pam.d/login to enable the pam_limits.so module:

```
session required /lib/security/pam_limits.so
```

limits.conf example content:

```
*               soft    core            0
*               hard    nofile          512
@student        hard    nproc           20
@faculty        soft    nproc           20
@faculty        hard    nproc           50
ftp             hard    nproc           0
@student        -       maxlogins       4
:123            hard    cpu             5000
@500:           soft    cpu             10000
600:700         hard    locks           10
```

Additional documentation:

- http://www.serverwatch.com/server-tutorials/set-user-limits-with-pamlimits-and-limits.conf.html
- https://linux.die.net/man/8/pam_limits
- https://linux.die.net/man/5/limits.conf